# What kind of distribution is this

Tags: statistics

$$f(x,\theta) = \begin{cases}1/\theta,& \theta \leq x\leq 2\theta\\
0,& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Is this a geometric distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the uniform distribution on $[\theta, 2\theta]$.